# Move characters to the end of a string in scala

Tags: string, scala

I have a file with following type of strings:

```
1 2 a 3 4
5 b 6 c 7
```

I wanna move all the letters to the end of string, so the output will be:

```
1 2 3 4 a
5 6 7 b c
```

I tried this way:

```
line.replaceAll("\\D+", "") + line.replaceAll("\\d+", "")
```

but it gives the output as:

```
1234    a
567   b c
```

I wanna preserve the white space and get the output with all the letters at the end for any arbitrary number of lines.

**PS: I am writing a code for spark-scala so please show me a scala way**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you have `file.txt` with the following contents:

```
1 2 a 3 4
5 b 6 c 7
10 b c 11 12
```

You could use `map`, `split`, `toList`, `sorted` and `mkString` to achieve your desired result:

```
import java.io.File
import java.io.PrintWriter
import scala.io.Source

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val f = new File("file.txt")
    val temp = new File("file.tmp")
    val w = new PrintWriter(temp)
    Source
      .fromFile(f)
      .getLines
      .map { x =>
        x
          .split(' ')
          .toList
          .sorted
          .mkString(" ")
      }
      .foreach(x => w.println(x))
    w.close()
    temp.renameTo(f)
  }
}
```

`file.txt` after running above:

```
1 2 3 4 a
5 6 7 b c
10 11 12 b c
```

Comment: Thanks @[Shash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6328256/shash-sinha) worked perfectly... I was reading the file in rdd and rdd mapped brilliantly...thanks once again...simple and elegant...Kudos

Comment: No problem, I used scala at my internship last year was really fun!

Comment: `.split(" ")` is more expensive than `.split(' ')` _(note the single quotes)_ - Also no need to `.toList` before `sorted`, since an **Array** can also be sorted.

Comment: I used `toList` since I saw "If you want to sort an Array, see my other FAQ on How to sort an Array in Scala." on the cookbook site: https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-sort-scala-sequences-seq-list-array-buffer-vector-ordering-ordered/. Basically I assumed he meant not to use `.sorted` on Array.

Comment: Did not know that you could use `.split(' ')` or the performance benefits, changed it, thanks.

Comment: @ShashSinha yeah in general plain **Arrays** in **Scala** are discouraged and rather one should use proper collections like **List**, as such I myself recommend doing a `toList` after a `split` most of the time. However, given here we will just sort it and then turn it again into a **String** the `toList` is just unnecessary and somewhat expensive. - About `split(" ")` vs `split('  ')` the former is a simple split by character, so the implementation just goes in a simple loop, whereas the first one is a split by regex so the implementation is somewhat more complex.

Comment: Thanks guys....The explanation of two different splits was an added bonus to this question :)

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Makes sense, in Java, [`split`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) requires the regex to be a string, I didn't know it was different in Scala.

Comment: @ShashSinha it is not different, is the same actually since **Scala's** `String` is **Java's** `String` the same point is valid in **Java**. If you only want to split for a single character it is better to use the `split` variant that accepts a single character.

Comment: Just tried on Java 11 I am getting `error: incompatible types: char cannot be converted to String` when I try: `String s = "zxc vb"; System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split(' ')));`

Comment: @ShashSinha oh it seems I was wrong, the `split` version that takes a `Char` is not part of the **Java** `String` but of the **Scala** one, and at the end calls the same method that uses a **regex** so it should be the same. Source: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.4/src/library/scala/collection/StringOps.scala#L820

Answer (score 2):

The main problem with your current approach is that the second replacement also needs to remove whitespace, otherwise it will only remove digits, but leave behind both letters and spaces.  Then, you need an additional step to reintroduce the original spaces in between each character. Assuming you wanted to use a Java-esque approach, you could  try:

```java
// Java version.
String line = "5 b 6 c 7";
String output = line.replaceAll("\\D+", "") +
                line.replaceAll("[\\d\\s]+", "");
output = output.replaceAll("(?=.)", " ");
System.out.println(output);
```

```scala
// Scala version.
val line = "5 b 6 c 7"
var output = line.replaceAll("\\D+", "") +
             line.replaceAll("[\\d\\s]+", "")
output = output.replaceAll("(?=.)", " ")
println(output)
```

Both prints:

```
5 6 7 b c
```

Comment: Thanks @[Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1863229/tim-biegeleisen). It was really helpful both for Java and Scala.. but the same problem as with [Luis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4111404/luis-miguel-mej%c3%ada-su%c3%a1rez) when I enter the line as **"10 b c 11 12"** the output is: **1 0 1 1 1 2 b c**

Comment: and [Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1863229/tim-biegeleisen) please can you explain me the regex in  **output.replaceAll("(?=.)", " ")**....I am new to regex...Thanx

Comment: @HasnainMotagamwala For your updated requirement (not what you asked originally), you will have to do a sort to separate numbers from letters.  I don't know how to do that in Scala (but Luis probably does).

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage that characters are sorted according to their order in the [**ASCII** table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

```scala
def sortStringWithSpaces(str: String): String =
  str.split(' ').sorted.mkString(" ")
```

Which you can use like this:

```scala
sortStringWithSpaces("1 2 a 3 4")
// res: String = "1 2 3 4 a"

sortStringWithSpaces("5 b 6 c 7")
// res: String = "5 6 7 b c"

sortStringWithSpaces("10 b c 11 12")
// res: String = "10 11 12 b c"
```

---

You can see the code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/nRPrwMTJSQq1lfBTvDW6oA/2).

Comment: Thanks [Luis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4111404/luis-miguel-mej%c3%ada-su%c3%a1rez) for answering so readily....This works just fine but when I am trying numbers above 9 it fails as...... **sortStringWithSpaces("10 b c 11 12")** gives: 
**0 1 1 1 1 2 b c**

Comment: Thanks @[Luis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4111404/luis-miguel-mej%c3%ada-su%c3%a1rez) for replying again...Already accepted Shash's answer but your has a step less of not converting to List...Will keep this in mind.....BTW [TimBiegeleisen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1863229/tim-biegeleisen) answer was completely fine...Someone looking this for Java can benefit from his answer.

Answer (score 2):

I know I am a bit late, but another thing you can do is:

```
def sortStringWhitspaces(str: String): String = {
  val partitioned = str.split(' ').partition(x => Try(x.toInt).isSuccess)
  (partitioned._1 ++ partitioned._2).mkString(" ")
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that you don't sort the numbers and letters. First, you didn't specify in the question if you need to preserve the original order, but sorting is not doing that. The second thing, sorting might have efficiency footprint, while this solution is `O(n)`.

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/ZiHsM9irTliOieEiki0Bpg/1).

Comment: Smart, essential and elegant. His initial question implies preserving the order.

Comment: Thanks, as I said in my answer, it is ambiguous. It can be either order preserved, or sorted. All examples are sorted so it is really hard to tell.

Comment: Thank you @[Tomer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2359227/tomer-shetah). Just a follow up question: how to know if a method is available in earlier versions of scala also like if we have to check that **partition** is available in 2.11 and 2.12 also, how can we find that, like from which version this method was included in scala

Comment: @HasnainMotagamwala It is available in early scala versions. You can either try it, or search the docs.